# Keyboard shortcut for Revisions > Hide Revision Information in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, keyboard-shortcuts

I have set up a keyboard shortcut for 'Show Annotations' in my Java source files since I frequently want to know when a Git revision was made, and sometimes by whom. The thick margin on the left with lots of colors, which is pretty distracting while coding, so I would like to toggle it off with a keyboard command.

Following the advice at [help.eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-cvs-annotate.htm) in order to toggle the revision information off I'm now moving my pointer to the margin, right-clicking, selecting `Revisions`, and clicking `Hide Revision Information`. Is there a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to Hide Revision Information? If not, is there a different way to achieve the action that I can shortcut?

I have EGit installed (although I use it as little as humanly possible), if it matters.

Comment: How about using `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Q` for toggling quick diff which will turn off show annotations.

Comment: @AleksandrM It doesn't actually turn off show annotations - this is the diff that shows colors and a mouseover message on the line numbers - I'm talking about the author name + full commit message on hover to the left of the line numbers. Thanks though! Very close

Comment: It is seems that quick diff toggle works differently if you have line numbers toggled on, or rather not working. ;)

Comment: I prefer to have the line numbers well colored so I set a Ctrl + A shortcut for the show Annotations and selected by default show revision autor. Only i have problems when i want to close the annotation, then i have to right click with the mouse and select Hide Revision Information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a full answer to my question, but there's a coping mechanism: `Toggle Revision Author Display`. With the toggle for author the most annoying part can be turned off: taking space for author name. The colors still remain, however.

As @AleksandrM mentioned the Quick Diff toggle does achieve the goal - but **it does not work** when line numbers are shown. In case line numbers are shown it just toggles the revision information on the line numbers, and shows changes compared to Head in your current file with Quick Diff colors.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a trick. Use *"Show Ruler Context Menu"*-Short-Cut (`Ctrl + F10`), then `V` (for: Re**V**ison), and then `H` (for: **H**ide Revision Information).

So, whole Short-Cut looks like this: `Ctrl + F10, V, H`